# Java 8 compare 2 lists based on one property

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream, list-comprehension

I have 2 list of **Product** objects
And I want to compare these 2 lists to identify if there are any **product_price_last_updated_time_stamp** is different between these two lists for the same product.

I can do this is Java 7, by putting 2 for each loops
But I would like to achieve this is Java 8 (with Streams and filters)

Here is my example in **Java 7**

```
List<Product> list1;
List<Product> list2;

for(Product p1 : list1) {
    for(Product p2 : list2) {
        if(!p1.getProduct_price_last_updated_time_stamp().equals(p2.getProduct_price_last_updated_time_stamp()) {
            System.out.print("This product price has been updated: "+p1.getProductName());
        }
    }
}
```

Also can someone help me in understanding the differences in performance between Java 7 and Java 8

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: No code provided, no answers on how to alter the code...

Comment: Don't talk poetry show us the code.

Comment: Share at least  what you have done with  java 7

Comment: You can do it in Java 8 “by putting 2 for each loops” as well.

Comment: Added code snippet, which I tried using Java 7, please help me in writing the same in Java 8

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
    list1.stream()
            .flatMap(x -> list2
                    .stream()
                    .filter(y -> x.getId() == y.getId())
                    .filter(y -> !x.getLastUpdated().isEqual(y.getLastUpdated()))
                    .limit(1))
            .forEach(product -> System.out.println("Product price has been updated: " + product.getName()));
```

I have assumed that your `priceLastUpdated` property is of `LocalDateTime` type. You can call the relevant `equals()` method instead of `isEqual()` that I used above if you are using some other type.

You mentioned "*for the same product*", but your code doesn't check if the product is the same. I used `id` to check if it's the same product `x.getId() == y.getId()`. You can use whatever field you like.

As for the performance, there is no practical difference between Java 7 and 8 if coded properly. I am saying "practical difference" because there are a lot of factors involved in finding out the precise difference, if at all possible.

In your code sample though, you are not breaking the loop even if a match is found, which is very inefficient.